# Convert float to string in R without losing precision

Tags: r, string

I need to convert a dataframe of floats with 2-decimal point precision to strings. However, as.character drops zeros in the decimal part:

```
> as.character(1.00)
[1] "1"
> as.character(1.10)
[1] "1.1"
```

I want these numbers to stay in the original format, i.e.:

```
> paste0(1, ".00")
[1] "1.00"
> paste0(1, ".10")
[1] "1.10".
```

Currently I plan to run for loop, checking string length and applying paste0() across my dataframe, but it seems really stupid to me. Is there simple way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%0.2f", 1.10)
#[1] "1.10"
sprintf("%0.2f", 1.00)
#[1] "1.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the format function with the `nsmall` argument to be 2.

```
format(1, nsmall = 2)
# [1] "1.00"
format(1.1, nsmall = 2)
# [1] "1.10"
```