# number(3.40) convert to character('3.40') not character('3.4') in R?

Tags: r

i try convert 3.40 to '3.40'

```
> as.character(3.40)
[1] "3.4"
> as.character(11.30)
[1] "11.3"
```

how I can achieve this

```
[1] "3.40"
[1] "11.30"
```

how to code?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53435742/3506405 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert float to string in R without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435742/convert-float-to-string-in-r-without-losing-precision)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%.2f", 3.4)
```

The number after the dot in the format string defines how many digits after the decimal point are shown.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `formatC` specifying the number of `digits` we want :

```
formatC(3.4, digits = 2, format = "f")
#[1] "3.40"
```